# Is adding list to itself safe in c#?

Tags: c#

Something like this:

```
List<int> l = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
l.AddRange(l);
```

Is it safe? I didn't find any point to this in the C# docs.

However [this code works as expected](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ky4Zun):

```
List<int> l = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
l.AddRange(l);

foreach(var i in l)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);   
}
```

With the result:

```
1,2,3,1,2,3
```

**Clarification**: **safe** means "don't cause memory corruption, undefined behaviour or something similar". So can I use this in my code without issuses.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `is safe`, because currently it is hard to get what exactly you are asking.

Comment: "Is it safe?" What do you mean by this? You can surely do this, it will just copy the elements from your list. If it works as expected what exactly is ypur question about?

Comment: Yes it is fine. It won't throw any exceptions or break code if that's what you mean by safe

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to duplicate elements there are other ways

Comment: @DanielLoudon that requires a bit more of an explanation. `It worked for me` isn't enough

Comment: you can do this 1000 times and there will be no error because the parameter L gets restored in a method-member-variable and then added to L where you called to add range.

Comment: This should be reopened because the *answer* isn't trivial. `Safe` probably means `will it corrupt the list?`. It won't but that's because of the internal workings of List

Comment: @LenglBoy that doesn't mean anything. 1000 times for a modern machine isn't even a single scheduling slice. There are other things that wont' fail until the 1001st attempt

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, we don´t know what OP means by safe. Your explanation is just one of dozens. And even yours ifn´t free of interpretation: what is corrupt? Does it mean will it modify the order? Will it delete duplicates? Will it even contain *anything*?

Comment: @HimBromBeere you didn't see it because you closed the question. Thread safe, no, AddRange isn't thread safe. Safe from corruption, yes, because `AddRange` *copies* the entire array into a new buffer. If you tried to add the items one by one in a loop, you'd get either an error message or infinite loop

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can *guess* what exactly OP would like to ask here, and there certainly would be room for a proper explanation. But unless OP actually bothers to clarify what they mean, I don’t think this question should be reopened. As it is *right now*, the question is unclear, even if you can up with a useful answer.

Comment: Your simple code sample is *safe*. Something else - doesn't necessarily will be. E.g. it's not thread safe (`AddRange`  will throw if collection is modified in another thread). If items are references (not value type as in your example), then new added items will be new references to same instance, etc. So there are a big gap for *undefined behavior*, which makes question too broad in my opinion. Though I vote for reopen, as I wonder what answers will be given here.

Comment: What makes you assume adding the same list using `AddRange` behaves different than adding another list via `AddRange`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Nothing. Just want to be absolutely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's safe.

Ordinary code that gets used to add any other list wouldn't automatically be safely written, but `InsertRange` (which is what `AddRange` ends up calling) specifically includes code to support this case:

[`List.cs`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs.html#51decd510e5bfe6e):

> ```
> // If we're inserting a List into itself, we want to be able to deal with that.
> if (this == c) {
>     [...code specifically for your use case]
> }
> else {
>     [...code for inserting other collections]
> }
> ```

That said, the specific code that's used today for inserting other collections *looks* like it should actually be safe even if `this == c`, but it gets called after internal state of the list has already been modified, so it would have been very error-prone. The benefit is that we now know that it's explicitly intended to work.

Comment: Thanks of point to source. MSDN docs says nothing of this behaviour [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Yaros Why should it mention it? How it works is implementation detail and not relevant to the user of `AddRange`. Unless explicitly said so, you should just assume that it works instead of the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

`Is it safe` is rather ambiguous.

If by it you mean `thread safe`, no. AddRange isn't a thread-safe method. In general, List isn't a thread safe collection.

If you mean `will it corrupt the list`, no it won't. If you check the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,245), the internal [InsertRange](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,701) method handles *both* self copying *and* ICollection classes in a special way.

In both cases, the code starts by enlarging the internal buffer so it can handle all the data.

In the case of [self-copying](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,720) the code simply copies the original buffer twice into the target buffer :

```
// If we're inserting a List into itself, we want to be able to deal with that.
if (this == c) {
    // Copy first part of _items to insert location
    Array.Copy(_items, 0, _items, index, index);
    // Copy last part of _items back to inserted location
    Array.Copy(_items, index+count, _items, index*2, _size-index);
}
```

When the input is a class that implements `ICollection<T>` (ie arrays and Lists), the code uses [ICollection.CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0efx51xw(v=vs.110).aspx) to copy the input data into a temporary buffer, then it copies it into the list's internal buffer :

```
T[] itemsToInsert = new T[count];
c.CopyTo(itemsToInsert, 0);
itemsToInsert.CopyTo(_items, index);
```

You can make this fail if the input can't be cast to an ICollection, eg. if you used LINQ on the list:

```
var list=new List<int>{1,2,3};
list.AddRange(list.Select(i=>i));
```

In this case, the runtime will detect that the list is being modified during an enumeration and throw an `InvalidOperationException` with the message `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute`

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
    List<int> l = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    foreach (var x in l)
    {
        l.Add(x);
    }
```

You will see that it fails since you can't modify a List while you enumerate it
[image]

AddRange doesn't enumerate the inserted collection, it uses Array.Resize and Array.Copy to resize the underlying array of the list and then copies the inserted collection into that array.

So technically, in a single thread scenario, it is safe.
It wouldn't be safe to run AddRange from different threads simultaneously since Array.Reize and Array.Copy aren't thread safe and might cause memory corruption.